# how to set taskbar thumbnail of a window in another window in pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

i am making 2 windows can i replace taskbar thumbnail using`QtWinExtras` of another window.I want to replace 1st window thumbnail by 2nd.like this image
[image]

I tried

```
def showEvent(self,event):
        self.thumbbar =QtWinExtras.QWinThumbnailToolBar(2nd window)
        self.thumbbar.setWindow(1st_window.windowHandle())
```

But nothing happend.Can it be done?If yes,can it be applicable for a `Splashscreen`type window?